# Scrapy simulated login redirected several times eventually gets back to login page

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I was using Scrapy to simulate a user login process to a website (sorry, I cannot share URL here). After sending proper username and password using FromRequest, the website redirect the login page (A) to B, then B gets redirected again to C, then strangely C back to A again; While what I was expecting is C, but it's always getting back to A. I am pretty sure about the correctness of my U/P as if I intentionally made it wrong, there's no redirection from the website. With this U/P input to browser, I can successfully reach to C.

My question is: how can I get to the page C with simulated user login in Scrapy?

The code:

```python
    class MusicSpider(Spider):
        name = 'music'
        start_urls = (
                 'https://www.example.com/aro/login/',
        )

        handle_httpstatus_all = True

        def parse(self, response):
            if response.status == 200:
                return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={
                               'p': 'password',
                               'u': 'username',
                               'keepin': '0',
                               },
                    callback=self.scrape_pages)

        def scrape_pages(self, response):
            if response.status == 302:
                filename = 'fly-1.html'
                open_in_browser(response)
                if (os.path.exists(filename)):
                    os.remove(filename)
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.body)
                self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Here below is the Scrapy running log:

> 2020 5:51:45 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2020
>   5:51:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2020 5:51:45
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2020 5:51:45
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:5026 2020 5:51:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received cookies from: <200 https://www.example.com/aro/login/>
>   Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin/
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/
>
> 2020 5:51:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.example.com/aro/login/> (referer: None) 2020 5:51:49
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to:
>   https://www.example.com/aro/login> Cookie: c5ib=0
>
> 2020 5:51:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received
>   cookies from: <302 https://www.example.com/aro/login> Set-Cookie:
>   c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin/
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=00000000000000107711SL6yKs8iiluvP0gfZ8X3Rz; Secure;
>   HttpOnly; Path=/
>
> 2020 5:51:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG:
>   Redirecting (302) to https://www.example.com/aro> from https://www.example.com/aro/login> 2020 5:51:50
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: https://www.example.com/aro> Cookie:
>   c5ib=00000000000000107711SL6yKs8iiluvP0gfZ8X3Rn
>
> 2020 5:51:51 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG:
>   Redirecting (302) to https://www.example.com/bin/c5i> from https://www.example.com/aro> 2020 5:51:51
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: https://www.example.com/bin/c5i> Cookie: c5ib=0; c5ib=0;
>   c5ib=00000000000000107711SL6yKs8iiluvP0gfZ8X3Rn
>
> 2020 5:51:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG:
>   Redirecting (302) to https://www.example.com/aro/login> from https://www.example.com/bin/c5i> 2020 5:51:55
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Sending cookies to: https://www.example.com/aro/login> Cookie:
>   c5ib=00000000000000107711SL6yKs8iiluvP0gfZ8X3Rn
>
> 2020 5:51:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] DEBUG: Received
>   cookies from: <200 https://www.example.com/aro/login> Set-Cookie:
>   c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin/
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/bin
>
> Set-Cookie: c5ib=0; Expires=Thu Jan  1 16:00:00 1970 GMT; Path=/
>
> 2020 5:51:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.example.com/aro/login> (referer:
>   https://www.example.com/aro/login/) 2020 5:51:56 [scrapy.core.engine]
>   INFO: Closing spider (finished)

Comment: you should include what is the website, you are trying to login into,anyway you might benefit from using REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES in your request meta